# How to animate CSS3 Transform in JQuery

Tags: animation

I want to make a simple animation with CSS3 Transform rotate in JQuery but it seems it is not working. Here my codes below:

```
<script>
function sun() {
    $('#sun').animate({opacity:0.5, '-webkit-transform':'rotate(360deg)'},5000).animate({opacity:1, '-webkit-transform':'rotate(-360deg)'},5000);
    setTimeout('sun()',2000);   
}
    $(document).ready (function() {
        sun();
    });
</script>
```

Help

Comment: NEVER use `setTimeout` with strings (it's like the devil `eval`)!!! Use `setTimeout(sun,2000);` instead!

Comment: What you mean just use a CSS animation? I want the animation to continue, this is why I am using JQuery instead of Keyframes etc in CSS3.